# (Light) gray colors not showing, not due monitor

Tags: colors, windows-7

My colleague's monitor is not showing (light) gray colors. 
I have the same monitor, but don't have this problem.

Example below (middle box should be light gray)
[image]

Can someone advise me where to look for this?
PC: Windows 7

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change the **contrast** values in the video settings.

Comment: @Nields Thank you, this fix my issue